# Determining If jQuery UI Draggable Is Initialized

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Is there a way of testing to determine if a `jQuery UI draggable` class has been initialized?

I have a series of divs with the class "draggable1".

For reasons beyond the scope of this question, I do not want to initialize the class in advance, rather I need to initialize the class the first time one of the divs is selected, which I do in a click event handler. Then, I assume I don't want to keep re-initializing the class every time another div is selected. So, I need to determine if one of the divs has already been clicked and initializing the draggable is not necessary.

Or am I looking at this incorrectly? Should I simply re-initialize the draggable class every time another div is selected?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you are using jQuery UI 1.9+ (specify your version if not), you can retrieve your draggable div data to check if draggable is initialized using :

```
jQuery('.draggable1').data('ui-draggable');
```

Your click handler function will look like :

```
$('.draggable1').click(function() {
    var $div = $(this);
    if(!$div.data('ui-draggable'))
        $div.draggable();
});
```

See it in action in this <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uZvN6/3)</kbd>

**Explanation** : the jquery UI draggable widget is based on the [jQuery UI widget factory](http://api.jqueryui.com/jquery.widget/) and as described in the 'Instance' section of the documentation :

> The widget's instance is stored using jQuery.data() with the widget's full name as the key.

You can also use the [:data](http://api.jqueryui.com/data-selector/) selector to check if your div element already has a draggable widget bound to it :

```
$div.is(':data(ui-draggable)');
```

Comment: Needless to say, I got tired of looking around for a good example or plugin for a multi-select draggable design, so I decided to develop my own. This is just what I needed to do it. Thank you very much.

Comment: One point of confusion --- I would have expected to see all the divs initialized once one had been initialized, since they're part of the same class. I noticed that if you initialize the class in advance, then each div acquires an additional ui-draggable class at the time it is dragged. I think I'm confusing the class assigned to the div with the actual instantiated draggable widget.

Comment: If you use `$('.draggable1').draggable()`, all divs with css class 'draggable1' will be initialized at once (the draggable widget is applied to each element matched by the selector).

Whereas the code i wrote bind a click handler function to each element with css class 'draggable1'.
Once you click on one div, only this one is made draggable by `$div.draggable();`.

If you want to initialize all of them when one div is clicked, just replace the `$div.draggable();` by `$('.draggable1').draggable()`

Comment: I edited the jsFiddle to reflect changes, tell me if it feets your needs. To clarify a little: css classes are indeed not the widget instance. Your divs have css class '.draggable1' used to select elements on which draggable widget will be applied. 
When the widget is applied to one div, a widget instance is created and attached to your div element using jQuery `.data(...)`. Also a css class 'ui-draggable' is automatically added to your div when the widget is applied. The css class 'ui-draggable-dragging' is also added to your div while dragging and removed when dragging stop for example

Comment: It would help if I explain the reason for my original question. We have a fairly complicated page full of draggables and droppables. It originally contained a reference to its JavaScript file. When a drag and drop occurred, the page would refresh, thus reloading the JavaScript file. We changed that to a page that is all AJAX with no refreshing the page or JavaScript file when adding the multi-select functionality. Everything works well for awhile, but eventually things start to get unstable.

Comment: I assume I'm getting memory problems, so I'm looking for ways to initialize on demand and dispose of immediately after use. Based on our prior conversation, do I understand correctly that there really is only one draggable widget, regardless of the number of divs associated with the class. So, if I have three draggable classes - draggable 1, 2, and 3, I am not initializing and disposing of widgets for every div, but rather three widgets?

Comment: No, a widget instance is created for each div. But i have a page with about 100 draggable items (and 2 droppables) and no memory problems. It's quite hard to answer without viewing your code. You should open another more specific question with some code, cause we are no more talking about 'Determining If jQuery UI Draggable Is Initialized' :)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't need to be so complicated...

Just check using [jQuery's hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) like this:

```
var isDraggable = $(elem).hasClass("ui-draggable");

if (isDraggable) {
    //do stuff
}
```

All `draggable` elements get the `ui-draggable` class.